# Множество Insert и Update в одной транзакции

Tags: delphi, sql-server, transaction

Пытаюсь выполнить несколько insert и update в одной транзакции, так:

```
begin
  QueryPub.SQL.Clear;
  QueryPub.SQL.Text := Memo2.Text;
  QueryPub.Connection.BeginTrans; // Новая транзакция
  try
    QueryPub.ExecSQL;
    QueryPub.Connection.CommitTrans; // Подтверждаем изменения и закрываем транзакцию
    ShowMessage('Готово"');
  except
    On e: EDatabaseError do
      messageDlg(e.message, mtError, [mbOK], 0); // Что-то не так
    On e: EDatabaseError do
      QueryPub.Connection.RollbackTrans; // Ничего не меняем и вернуть ее в состояние до BeginTrans
  end;
end;
```

Первый раз все хорошо, но при повторном нажатии на кнопку получаю сообщение вроде
"Транзакция может быть только одна".
Подскажите как решить проблему!?
И правильно ли вообще я пытаюсь использовать транзакции?

---

> "И у вас при EDatabaseError Rollback не сработает"

```
On e: EDatabaseError do  
      begin  
        QueryPub.Connection.RollbackTrans; // Ничего не меняем и вернуть ее в состояние до BeginTrans  
        messageDlg(e.message, mtError, [mbOK], 0); // Что-то не так  
      end;
```

Comment: Приведите точное сообщение об ошибке. И у вас при `EDatabaseError` Rollback не сработает, т.к. после первого `do` исключение считается обработанным и после того, как отработает `MessageDlg`, произойдёт выход из `except` блока без каких-либо дальнейших проверок.

Comment: А что за компоненты? Может там CommitTrans - это commit retaining,т.е. транзакция остаётся открытой?

Comment: @Alekcbp QueryPub: TADOQuery;

Comment: Проверьте состояние `QueryPub.Connection.InTransaction` после вызова `CommitTrans` и перед вторым вызовом `BeginTrans` (когда ошибка выскакивает) - если они отличаются, значит где-то ещё транзакция стартует.

Comment: А если exception будет не типа EDatabaseError? Транзакция останется в подвешенном состоянии.

Comment: @kami собственно это и произошло.

Answer (score 0):

Транзакции используете правильно, но вот обработка исключений сделана неправильно.

Как я уже писал в комментариях, у вас при `EDatabaseError` rollback не сработает, т.к. после первого `do` исключение считается обработанным и после того, как отработает `MessageDlg`, произойдёт выход из `except` блока без каких-либо дальнейших проверок.

Кроме того, ваш код не учитывает, что могут возникнуть и другие типы исключений, при которых rollback так же не сработает.

Я бы порекомендовал делать обработку исключений в таком стиле:

```
begin
  QueryPub.SQL.Clear;
  QueryPub.SQL.Text := Memo2.Text;

  QueryPub.Connection.BeginTrans;
  try
    QueryPub.ExecSQL;
    QueryPub.Connection.CommitTrans;        
  except        
    QueryPub.Connection.RollbackTrans;
    raise;
  end;

  ShowMessage('Готово"');
end;
```

Обратите внимание, что после `CommitTrans` у вас больше не должно быть **ни одной строчки кода** до `except` блока.

Так же, нет никакой необходимости использовать `MessageDlg` внутри `except` блока. Просто пробросьте исключение дальше, используя `raise`.